# want to return percentage in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-spectacular

- I wanted to return the percentage of every poll `options_data` in response.
- I'm Expecting output Like in below.

```
{
    "response": true,
    "return_code": "remove_vote_success",
    "result": {
        "id": 9,
        "user_id": 2,
        "question": "what would you like to see more of on our channel?",
        "created_on": "2022-09-06T05:52:39",
        "active": true,
        "options_data": [
            {
                "id": 25,
                "poll_id": 9,
                "option_text": "Video editing tutorials",
                "percentage_count": 50.0
            },
            {
                "id": 26,
                "poll_id": 9,
                "option_text": "Clipchamp product updates",
                "percentage_count": 10.0
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "poll_id": 9,
                "option_text": "Social media growth tips"
                "percentage_count": 40.0
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "poll_id": 9,
                "option_text": "Clipchamp tips and tricks",
                "percentage_count": 0.0
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Vote get successfully."
}
```

- this is my **models.py**

```
class Polls(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="polls_data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Options(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Polls, related_name="options_data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="vote_data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Polls, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Options, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

- this is my **serializer.py**

```
class OptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Options
        fields = ('id', 'poll_id', 'option_text')

class PollsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    options_data = OptionsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Polls
        fields = ('id','user_id', 'question', 'created_on', 'active',  'options_data')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OptionsSerializer`add a field that takes the `.count()` of the option in question and divide by the `count()` of all answers for that question. (then multiply that by 100 to get to percentage)

```
class OptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    percentage_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    ...

    def get_percentage_count(self, obj): 
       total_votes = Vote.objects.filter(poll=obj.poll).count()
       share_of_votes = Vote.objects.filter(option=obj).count()
       return Decimal(
           (share_of_answers / total) * 100
       ).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
```

Answer (score 1):

if we return values direct in response there maybe you will face `ZeroDivisionError`.
so for code efficiency use this.

```
class OptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    percentage_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Options
        fields = ('id', 'poll_id', 'option_text', 'percentage_count')

    def get_percentage_count(self, obj): 
       total_votes = Vote.objects.filter(poll_id=obj.poll).count()
       share_of_votes = Vote.objects.filter(option_id=obj).count()
       try:
            percentage = Decimal((share_of_votes / total_votes) * 100).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
       except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0 
       return percentage

class PollsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    options_data = OptionsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Polls
        fields = ('id','user_id', 'question', 'created_on', 'active',  'options_data')
```

Comment: To improve performance a little little bit you can short circuit and return zero after the first row if `total_votes` is 0 to avoid hitting the database to get `share_of_votes`